# Android xml layout about CheckBox and RadioButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-checkbox, android-radiobutton

There have two RadioButton, Twelve Checkbox and one send button,each button has a custom selector.
RadioButton and Checkbox out of range, can not let all RadioButton and Checkbox in the android xml layout.
I used ScrollView, but it have some error about "Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child".
I don't know how can RadioButton and Checkbox in there range.
How to change RadioButton and CheckBox in to the RadioButton in there range?
thanks.

### [image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


       <ScrollView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          >


       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/etIdUserName2"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="10sp" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/etIdUseracc2"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="10sp" />

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/etIdPassre2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="使用者性別"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/boy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="男" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/girl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="女" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="使用者年齡"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/under"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="18以下"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/between2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="23~27"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/between1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="18~23"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/between3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="28~32"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="32以上"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="使用者興趣"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/girluse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="女裝與服飾配件、女包精品與女鞋"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/makeup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="美容保養與彩妝"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/boyuse"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="男性精品與服飾"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/electronicproduct"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="電腦、平板與周邊"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cellphone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="手機、配件與通"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/food"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="美食與地方特產"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/Stationery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="文具與事務用"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setbutton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="送出"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

             </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use a `ScrollView` if the content doesn't fit.

Comment: I used "ScrollView" . but it tell me " Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child "

Comment: The `ScrollView` must have a single child, in your case you'll need to make it wrap the top `LinearLayout`(the root `LinearLayout` in your xml layout).

Comment: have LinearLayout top ?

Answer (score 2):

"ScrollView can host only one direct child".

So simply wrap everything in a `LinearLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


       <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          >


       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/etIdUserName2"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="10sp" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/etIdUseracc2"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="10sp" />

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/etIdPassre2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="使用者性別"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/boy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="男" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/girl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="女" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="使用者年齡"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/under"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="18以下"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/between2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="23~27"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/between1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="18~23"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/between3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="28~32"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="32以上"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="使用者興趣"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/girluse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="女裝與服飾配件、女包精品與女鞋"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/makeup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="美容保養與彩妝"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/boyuse"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="男性精品與服飾"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/electronicproduct"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="電腦、平板與周邊"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cellphone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="手機、配件與通"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/food"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="美食與地方特產"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/Stationery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="文具與事務用"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setbutton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="送出"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the Logcat says `Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child`. One can have only one direct child view to `ScrollView`. As you have so many check boxes and RadioButton inside `ScrollView` it throws an error.

You just need to add all your `Checkbox` and `RadioButton` inside `View` with ParentView as `ScrollView` which can handle all your `RadioButton` and `Checkboxes`. In here I've added `Linearlayout` as `ParentView` for all your `Checkboxes` and `RadioButton`.

Explaination:

```
ScrollView // ParentView
   LinearLayout // DirectChild of ScrollView
      RadioButton & Checkboxes // Direct child of LinearLayout
```

Layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
   <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      >
   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
    >
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/etIdUserName2"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="10sp" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/etIdUseracc2"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="10sp" />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/etIdPassre2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="使用者性別"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/boy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="男" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/girl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="女" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="使用者年齡"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/under"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="18以下"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/between2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="23~27"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/between1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="18~23"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/between3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="28~32"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="32以上"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="使用者興趣"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/girluse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="女裝與服飾配件、女包精品與女鞋"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/makeup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="美容保養與彩妝"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/boyuse"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="男性精品與服飾"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/electronicproduct"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="電腦、平板與周邊"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cellphone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="手機、配件與通"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/food"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="美食與地方特產"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/Stationery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="文具與事務用"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setbutton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="送出"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
      </LinearLayout>
      </ScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>
```